# T-test for two groups with one group including only one value

Tags: r, t-test

How to run a t-test for two groups with one group including only one value?

Example:

```
group A: 7, 8, 9 
group B: 5
```

Comment: This can be done only if you assume the two groups have the same variance. But the test would be very weak.

Comment: @MichaelChernick With this assumption, it will be t.test(7:9, mu=5)? Thank you.

Comment: $\mu$ is unknown and not necessarily 5. But 5 would be the estimate of the group B mean and 8 the estimate of the group A mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, your suggested code is quite wrong.

The fact that there is only one observation for group B is not a problem for the standard two-sample t-test. You just run it in R in the usual way:

```
A <- c(7,8,9)
B <- 5
t.test(A, B, var.equal=TRUE)
```

The option var.equal=TRUE tells t.test() to perform the traditional two-sample t-test with pooled variance. In this case, the population variance is estimated from group A alone since replicates for group B are not available. The t-test will be on 2 degrees of freedom.